# Format string errors in Fortran with gfortran

Tags: format, fortran

I'm compiling an old .for file (Fortran 77) in gfortran for the first time and getting errors that I never saw previously (with another compiler that I no longer have access to). The errors are as follows:

smog5.for:159:32:

```
98   format (1x,f4.1,5x,14(1x,pe9.3))
```

1 Error: P descriptor requires leading scale factor in format string at (1)
smog5.for:161:35:

```
96   format (/'Emissions:',10(1x,pe9.3))
```

1 Error: P descriptor requires leading scale factor in format string at (1)
smog5.for:141:20:

```
      write (1,98) etime,(c(i),i=1,10),o,oh,rk(1),rk(6)
```

1 Error: FORMAT label 98 at (1) not defined
smog5.for:153:21:

```
       write (1,96) (E(i),i=1,10)
```

1 Error: FORMAT label 96 at (1) not defined

**The troublesome bits of code (within a much larger program) seem to be:**

```
  goto 10  

 98   format (1x,f4.1,5x,14(1x,pe9.3))
 97   format (/'end day',i2/)
 96   format (/'Emissions:',10(1x,pe9.3))

  end


  subroutine hybrid(n,c,rk,tin,tout,E,dep,vent,etime,o,oh,m,o2)
```

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong with the syntax here? Or is this something that would be solved with another compiler? I unfortunately don't have access to the previous compiler that worked, as it was on a secured server at a former school. I've translated the program to .f90 but get the same P descriptor errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `P` format specifier requires a digit in front, e.g., `1pe9.3`.  The `P` specifier behaves differently on input and output.  It's convenient for output but rather strange for input -- consult documentation.

The error messages about the format labels not being defined are a consequence of  the error with the format string (P descriptor) and should be solved when you fix that.

Comment: according to the docs for one compiler, the nonstandard P by itself is equivalent to 0P. (which would seem the same as no p at all, ...)

Comment: in this example, that is. `0p` resets prior p's. In this case there are none so it does nothing.

Comment: M.S.B, you rock! The previous fortran compiler I used assumed that (as agentp suggested), the non-specified P would be equivalent to 0P. But gfortran apparently doesn't! I added 1 integers as 1pe9.3 and it compiled properly. Thanks so much!

Comment: The agentp's concern was more if it will run correctly with 1 or 0. It should compile with both. Watch for strange values being read or written! There can be an error of 1 order of magnitude.